# Get a collection of products base on list of product id

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

Given a product `id`, I can query the product using

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

What I have is a list of ids (comma separated), I can `explode` it, loop through each id, and run `load($id)` like above. I am concern a bit about the performance. Is this a different way to handle it, something like `where` clause, with an `IN(id1,id2,id3,id4)` kind of syntax. I google around, and I see this

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAtributeToSelect('*')
```

I think I can add a filter to this, right? Had anyone solve a similar problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

1) Filter your collection using Product Ids you have :

```
$productIds = explode(',', "1,2,3,4,5,6");
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()-
>addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds));
```

2) If you want to retrive only specific information like name & sku etc, you can add attribute to select, this means collection will only fetch the name from database tables, rather than whole product information, you can select with below code

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','sku'));
```

3) Make Sure All this code is written in blocks or models and not in Phtmls, or else it can definitely affect the page speed.

Answer (score 1):

As par r requirement you can use finset function of magento which accepts array as parameter

Try to use addAttributeToFilter with or condition

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute,
    array(
        array('finset'=> array('237')),
        array('finset'=> array('238')),
        array('finset'=> array('239')),
    )
);
Or

$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=> 'attributecode','finset' => array('237')),
        array('attribute'=> 'attributecode','finset' => array('237')),
        array('attribute'=> 'attributecode','finset' => array('237')),
    )
);
```